# Delete all localization files and change standard language c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localization

how can I change the standard language in C# Designer? my Problem is that when I setup the localization to standard, the complete GUI crashed. Only my de-DE localization works. So I want to set the standard localization to de-DE, delete all other localizations and start from scratch.

Can anyone assist? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the neutral language of the application to German (de-DE).
To do so, open the project settings (right-click your C# project in `Visual Studio` and select `Properties`, go to `Application` (should be selected by default) and click on the `Assembly Information` Button. On the bottom of this dialog, the `Neutral language` can be set.

Comment: Tried that before but that dont set the real standard localization. Seems more like a start localization for the application.